# codeigniter glyphicons showing in blocks

Tags: codeigniter, glyphicons

I'm setting up CodeIgniter with bootstrap but when I'm trying to add a glyphicon icon then it's showing up as a block instead of the icon. I've linked bootstrap with

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

but its not working properly. everything is working so far only the glyphicons not. Does it have something to do with my htaccess file or... ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|bootstrap|design|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I hope someone can help me out, Sincerely Dennis

Comment: Can you show some code please? HTML and CSS, just regarding the glyphicon.

BTW your htaccess looks fine no worries about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set base_url in application/config/config.php file.
Ex: $config['base_url'] = 'url_of_your_site';

Comment: This could be the cause... One of the first things you should do is view the page source in your browser and ensure the links being generated are correct which would show this up.